# What does it mean for a theorem to be "delicate"?

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure what this means.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be very helpful to give context. At least, a full sentence, and possibly also the two preceding sentences of the source.

Comment: It is not a very precise word; it means, roughly: difficult, intricate, detailed, ornate.

Comment: In other words it needs to be "handled with care". (BTW, have you chosen "praying mantis" as your name, or is it just coincidentally that way in Pinyin?)

Comment: Sometimes it means, "The conditions are very specific, and any slight change in the conditions renders the conclusion invalid."

Comment: It is basically the same as when one writes "Handle with care" on a biochemical substance. It might be disastrous if used wrongly or with little care.

Answer (score 6):

Context would be useful, but I generally use it to mean the theorem requires several intricate hypotheses, all of which must be precisely stated in order to reach the desired conclusion. Such a theorem is "delicate" because it will not tolerate rough-handling (i.e. a quick and dirty statement of the hypotheses).

Comment: Yes, *delicate* in the sense of *easily breakable*.